# How do I manipulate records that I've returned to VF page?

Tags: apex

I want to update records for all the checkboxes that I've checked, however the getArtists is not accessible: `Variable does not exist: getArtists.`

Controller:

```
public artistWrapper[] getArtists(){
        return artistsList;
    }
    public PageReference mySave (){ 

        for(artistWrapper art: getArtists){

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Page:

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!artists}" var="cont" >

                <apex:column headerValue="Select" style="text-align:center">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cont.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over artistsList:

```
for(artistWrapper art: artistsList) {
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to use the function (slower, but you could), you need to actually call it as a function using parenthesis:

```
for(artistWrapper art: getArtists()) {
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I somehow thought that artistList wouldn't be updated from VF. Stupid me :)